# Computer silent after installation

Tags: windows-8, audio

My sound just died. I have newly installed Heos wireless speakers and I suspect maybe some settings have changed?

Speakers are plugged into from the back of the computer. They are set to default. I tried to exchange it for head phones but still silent. However in windows the mixer clearly shows that sound is being outputted. What other settings can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Based insufficient information I think you might have an incorrect setting in your audio output device. When changing from one Audio output device to another the "Default" output remains.

1. Right click on your sound icon and choose "Playback devices" `Or analogous, sorry my windows isn't in English`
2. On the newly open screen you should see all your Audio output devices. Plugged in and otherwise.  On the device you currently want to output sound from left click to select and below on press "Set as default"

Now your should have correct settings

Comment: Thanks but the speakers are already default. And i can see in the mixer that they have an audiosignal when playing music.

Comment: Well, in that case let's escalate it a bit. Have you tried turning your computer off and on again? I will assume so. Consider reinstalling your audio drivers. Press start, type "device manager"  and enter.  Navigate to your sound controllers trab and expand it. On the items listed there if you right click you can access their properties. Selecting uninstall without deleting the drivers will enable to you reinstall them on the same location.  Reboot after this and test if you issue persists.

Comment: Thanks! I uninstalled it. When i do, it dissapears from the device manager. Then i choose scan for hardware and it reapears already installed. But no sound. Then i restart but still no sound. Did i do it correctly?

Comment: Yes that works.  Are you quite sure your speakers are working? For control purposes try to plug in some earbuds that you know are good ( for instance they work on your phone). Check that you have the correct audio device set as default and listen if you have sound.  If you do, I think you actually have a problem with your speakers.

Comment: Ive done this already (as stated in OP). Ive connected headphones to the speakers head phone jack as well as straight into the soundcard jack where the speakers usually go.

Comment: I just tried connecting the speakers to my mobile so im sure the speakers work. I guess it could be the native soundcard thats broken?

Comment: Could be, but there is one more thing to try. Again, on your sound icon, right click select "playback devices" switch to the tab "advanced" (Or analogous). Now you should see a drop down menu with the bit sample quality and frequency settings. I believe it should be set at 24bit 480000hz (studio quality). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes  that is correct. When i press Test i hear nothing. And if i try to choose another option i get an error saying its already used somewhere else.

Comment: I just tried Restore Default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84680/discussion-between-ricardo-s-and-lautaro).

Comment: pointed me to the devices advanced settings where Restore Defaults did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First check if ur PC is giving audio outputs. 
Play some audio , then go to the speaker icon on the extreme left of the task bar. Click on it and check If there are green bar going up and down according to the music. If u do see it and ur PC doesn't give sound , then check ur audio device or your audio port. Or your soundcard might not be working. Most likely your speakers have gone bad. Or try reinstalling your audio drivers.